# REST call returns 200 but no desired change due to POST

Tags: java, api

I have the below response from a REST call when used with postman.The Response code is 200 :
[image]

I am trying to write some code to make the REST call :

```js
HttpHost httpHostTag = getMMCHost(prop);
System.out.println(httpHostTag);
//@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = (DefaultHttpClient) verifiedClient(new DefaultHttpClient());
HttpGet httpostTag = verifiedGet(urlTagUpdate, Mmc_user, Mmc_password);


HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpHostTag, httpostTag);

System.out.println(response.getParams());
int respCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

System.out.println("response Code for Tag Update API Call  : " + respCode);
String Code = Integer.toString(respCode);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();



if (entity != null) {
  InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
  result = convertStreamToString(instream);
  //resultMsg = result.split(",")[0].split(":")[1];
  resultMsg = result.split(",")[0].split("msg")[1];
  System.out.println(resultMsg);
  System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + result);
  instream.close();
}



if (Code.equals("200") || Code.equals("202") || Code.equals("204")) {
  System.out.println(resultMsg);

  //    return "RESPONSE : " + resultMsg;
} else {
  return "Error : " + result;
}

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("error in code ");
  e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Tag Update to setenv.sh .................. This will take around 10 sec ");
try {

  Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  // you probably want to quit if the thread is interrupted

}





return null;

}
```

In the split msg section above, I am getting errors. Nevertheless, even if I comment that section of the code,I am able to make the REST call. The call goes through and returns 200 as code. But it doesnot do any change as the REST call is supposed to do.

The REST url is correct as through POSTMAN it works perfect.

Any idea where I am making a mistake in the above code ?

Comment: "_In the split msg section above, I am getting errors._" What errors?

Comment: Index out of bounds :1 ............But this is only to display the result msg and doesnot impact the primary motive to make the REST call.The fact that the response code is 200(which is same when run from POSTMAN) suggest that the REST call is going through fine.The problem is that despite reurning correct code, it doesnot do the POST changes which the primary reason I am making the call.